# Changing the positioning to absolute to contain a word cloud

Tags: javascript, d3.js, word-cloud

I wrote the following code to generate a word cloud in D3:

HTML

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>D3 Word Cloud for Textual Data</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-sheet.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-cloud/1.2.5/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>

    <svg width="500" height="300"></svg>

    <script src="data-script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.word {
    font-size: 2em;
    fill: steelblue;
}
```

JS

```
var data = ["hello", "world", "d3", "word", "cloud", "visualization"];

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var layout = d3.layout
    .cloud()
    .size([width - margin.left - margin.right, height - margin.top - margin.bottom])
    .words(data.map(function (d) { return { text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 20 }; }))
    .padding(5)
    .rotate(function () { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
    .fontSize(function (d) { return d.size; })
    .on("end", draw);

layout.start();

function draw(words) {
    g.selectAll(".word")
        .data(words)
        .join("text")
        .attr("class", "word")
        .style("font-size", function (d) { return d.size + "px"; })
        .style("fill", function (d, i) { return "steelblue"; })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        })
        .text(function (d) { return d.text; });
}
```

But then I noticed the words are sometimes cut off and spilled over outside of the SVG element. I could not figure out how to fix it (other than playing with font size and padding which did not always work) so I asked for advice and I was told: *Change the absolute positioning!*

So, I modified my css code as following:

```
.word {
    font-size: 2em;
    fill: steelblue;
    position: absolute;
}
```

But that did not work either...

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you done is perfect but the grouping element g has wrong translation values.

> Use half of width and height to center the g element. Then every word will become inside of svg.

```js
var data = ["hello", "world", "d3", "word", "cloud", "visualization"];

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")");//center the g element by taking half of height and width

var layout = d3.layout
    .cloud()
    .size([width - margin.left - margin.right, height - margin.top - margin.bottom])
    .words(data.map(function (d) { return { text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 20 }; }))
    .padding(5)
    .rotate(function () { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
    .fontSize(function (d) { return d.size; })
    .on("end", draw);

layout.start();

function draw(words) {
    g.selectAll(".word")
        .data(words)
        .join("text")
        .attr("class", "word")
        .style("font-size", function (d) { return d.size + "px"; })
        .style("fill", function (d, i) { return "steelblue"; })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        })
        .text(function (d) { return d.text; });
}
```

```css
.word {
    font-size: 1em;
    fill: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-cloud/1.2.5/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>

    <svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you! Using half of width and height to center the g element is a great solution. Cheers

Comment: Its okay, Happy coding